Only "Manual Installation" Avaliable Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop.
Unfortunately, there is no "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option on the website/tutorial for
install (step 6, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation)
The option simply isn't there, forcing me to select "Manual Installation" which forces me to partition my disks and seems much more complex.
-This is on a pretty low end Acer Aspire (n19c3), which also has Windows 10 installed.  If I can get Ubuntu working, I don't really care to keep Windows on it.
I tried searching for this problem, including on here and couldn't find anything, this is also my first question so I apologize if it was done poorly.
The image shows step 6 of the tutorial for installing Ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation 

It can also happen if part of the disk is currently being used; eg. a live session has started & due to command/operation done by user a partition was mounted (which can include swap which doesn't need to be mounted directly by user, but can be mounted due to action of user without them noticing that it was)

@guiverc Interestingly, I wasn't given the option to try vs. install Ubuntu which is what I believe you meant by a live session (trying).  I have booted it from a USB though.
-Note, I'm still looking into karel's input, but the disk being used makes more sense as I am getting a popup that I'm "Failing to mount" 910 mb volume : "Error mounting /dev/loop2 at /media/ubuntu/disk: /dev/loop2 already mounted or mount point busy".  I probably should've included that in the first question

This is a Question and Answer site; so if you've solved it, please write your Solution in the Answer section of the page. Well done for solving it yourself !!!  (Self answers are okay on Q&A sites; we appreciate others trying to pass on solutions they've discovered).

SOLUTION: I was attempting to install from the Ubuntu RELEASE (which is in the top left, and shares the same icon as the Ubuntu Install but with limited options).  The Ubuntu Install is in the bottom right, and worked for me.
I feel silly now but that's resolved those issues, and I appreciate the two that commented on this !
